# Why does HtmlUnitDriver fail randomly (FirefoxDriver/ChromeDriver works)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, htmlunit-driver

I have one 2 min script for **Selenium webdriver**. It works very fine with **FirefoxDriver** and **ChromeDriver**. It never gets fails with real browser.

But when I run with **HTMLUnit** driver I have found Its fails randomly. Throws exception like not able to find element.

**Solutions that I have tried out :**

1. Add Thread.sleep to 6000 ms. But still not run every-time
2. Add wait but it throws error at same line
3. Change locator of element from Id to xpath or CSS path.

**Configuration and Versions:**

selenium-java : 2.53.0

selenium-server : 2.53.0

htmlunit-driver : 2.21

TestNG : 6.8.8

Comment: HtmlUnitDriver has a very different implementation (it doesn't really use another browser). So, it is more limited and will generally fail more often.

Answer (score 1):

Add explicit wait for the elements that WebDriver throws exception of unable to find element, as given below -

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WeBDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
```

Also, ensure that you have added below dependencies to your project -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
<version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have add 30 Second in wait but still found this error. Project has updated libraries. I have also included both dependencies.

Comment: Can you give more details on selenium-support ?

Comment: Selenium-support is required as per official page of HtmlUnitDriver - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver

Comment: It would be great if you could share your script and relevant necessary details so that it could be tried to reproduce.

Comment: I can not because some policies. But I can surely tell I have tried above solutions but still not able to get perfect results.

Comment: try enabling the javascript - driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true); other than this you can also try to enable debug logging HtmlUnitDriver and see if you get any clue from the logs.